# How to insert data from one table to another in oracle from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a daily table and a history table in my Oracle database. At the end of each day, I am looking to insert data from the daily table to the history table, then truncate the daily table. The catch is I am must insert the data in chunks of 5000 entries, and we are working with about 5 million entries total. I'm very new to PL/SQL and could use some help writing the stored procedure that would work for this scenario.

The first procedure using an all-at-once approach looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure test
is ts timestamp := current_timestamp;

begin
   insert into t_history
   select t.*, substr(USER, 1, 15), ts
   FROM t;
end test;
```

My question is, how can I refactor the above approach to load the data in chunks of 5000 entries and commit after each insert, rather than all at once?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi , did you  try with SQL and saw how much time it is taken, is the t_history table partitioned. If you are in 11g and afterward,it will be good if you do a interval partitioning of the t_history table on the date. Try with /*+ APPEND */ hint and see it may improve performance.

Comment: Why must you limit it? This is an artificial "requirement".  What takes more time, eating a whole pizza, or a pizza that has been cut into eight slices?

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `LIMIT` and `FETCH` may be helpful. More here: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-fetch/